# How do I add text in a flowchart without a border and how do I move my chart to the right and un-attach my top text with the chart?

Tags: tables, formatting, tikz-arrows, flow-charts

Greetings so like the title I have this code and I want you to help me with these problems:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

%% array
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%% enumitem
\setlist[enumerate]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\setlist[itemize]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}

%% titlesec
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter: }
    {0em}
    {\centering} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{20pt}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

%% tikz
\tikzset{
  block/.style = {
    rectangle,
    draw,
    text width=5em,
    text centered,
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
  },
  line/.style = {
    draw,
    -latex',
  },
  text/.style = {textwidth = 3em}
}

%% personal commands
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\School[1]{\gdef\@School{#1}}
\newcommand*\Department[1]{\gdef\@Department{#1}}
\newcommand*\Author[1]{\gdef\@Author{#1}}
\newcommand\Maketitle{%
  \author{\@Author\\\@School, \@Department}%
  \maketitle
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


%% final settings
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Bài}}
\linespread{1.05}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\title{{\Huge Science}}
\Author{{\large Generic Asian}}
\School{{\large Generic High school}}
\Department{{\large Class of 2020}}
\date{{\large Dunno}}
\Maketitle
\label{single}
\let\oldchapter\thechapter
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}\texttt{+}\the\numexpr\value{chapter}+1\relax}
\chapter{Sản xuất giống cây trồng}

\section{Mục đích của công tác sản xuất giống cây trồng}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Duy trì, củng cố độ thuần chủng, sức sống và tính trạng điển hình của giống
    \item Tạo ra số lượng giống cần thết để cung cấp cho sản xuất đại trà
    \item Đưa giống tốt phổ biến vào sản xuất
\end{itemize}
\section{Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng}

Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng gồm 3 giai đoạn

\vspace{3ex}

\medskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm, auto]
    \node [block] (bl1) {Hạt giống SNC};
    \node [block, below of=bl1, node distance=2cm] (bl2) {Hạt giống \\ NC};
    \node [block, below of=bl2, node distance=2cm] (bl3) {Hạt giống XN};
    \node [below right of = bl3, node distance=3cm] (bl4) {Sản xuất đại trà};

    \path [line] (bl1) -- (bl2);
    \path [line] (bl2) -- (bl3);
    \path [line] (bl3) |- (bl4);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | M{4em} | M{4cm}| M{4cm} |  } 
\hline
 & \textbf{Chất lượng, độ thuần, nguồn gốc} &\textbf{Nơi thực hiện}  \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Hạt siêu nguyên chủng} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt SNC & Công ty, trung tâm sản xuất giống cây trồng \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Hạt xác nhận} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt NC & Cơ sở nhân giống, trung tâm và các cơ sở sản xuất để sản xuất đại trà \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\section{Quy trình sản xuất giống cây trồng}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | M{3em} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | }
        \hline
         & \textbf{Cây tự thụ phấn} &\textbf{Cây thụ phấn chéo} 
         & \textbf{Cây nhân giống vô tính} & \textbf{Cây rừng}  \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Đặc điểm} & Hoa lưỡng tính \ Thời gian chin của nhị và nhụy cùng lúc & Hoa đơn tính hoặc hoa có thời gian chín của nhị và nhụy không cùng lúc & Sinh sản không có sự kết hợp giới đực và cái, con cái giống nhau và giống mẹ & Vòng đời dài \linebreak Từ 5 – 10 năm \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Vật liệu khởi đầu}  & Hạt siêu nguyên chủng & Hạt siêu nguyên chủng & Thế hệ vô tính đạt chuẩn siêu nguyên chủng & Cây trội có đặc tính tốt đã qua khảo nghiệm\\
         \hline
         \textbf{Cách li} & Không yêu cầu cách li cao & Yêu cầu cách li cao & Không cần cách li & Trong điều kiện rừng giống hoặc vườn giống\\
         \hline
         \textbf{Thời gian} & 4 – 5 năm & 4 vụ & & 1 vụ \\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Problem 1: Can you have arrow pointing at some text without it being boxed in a flowchart?

Problem 2: The text Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng gồm 3 giai đoạn is connected to the flowchart but i want it to be seperated from the flowchart by at least 2cm or what ever you want it to be?

Problem 3: So I want a way that the flowchart and the table to be in one line so that the Quy trình sản xuất giống cây trồng table can fit in one page

It is a lot to ask for and I will be sincerely grateful for anyone to help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document. And make it minimal. In fragment is mised some nodes style definitions.

Comment: Also are missed column definition, used document class etc. To be your question more clear, please provide a sketch of what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

[image: z]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{SNC} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{NC} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{XN} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\setlist[itemize]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{0em}{\centering} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{20pt}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*\School[1]{\gdef\@School{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\Department[1]{\gdef\@Department{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\Author[1]{\gdef\@Author{#1}}
\newcommand\Maketitle{%
    \author{\@Author\\\@School, \@Department}%
    \maketitle
}

\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Bài}   
\makeatother    

\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}    

\begin{document}
    
    \title{{\Huge Công Nghệ 10}}
    \Author{{\large Võ Khắc Phú Cường}}
    \School{{\large THPT Nam Sài Gòn}}
    \Department{{\large 10A1}}
    \date{{\large 2021 – 2022}}
    \Maketitle
\chapter{ Sản xuất giống cây trồng}
    
\section{Mục đích của công tác sản xuất giống cây trồng}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Duy trì, củng cố độ thuần chủng, sức sống và tính trạng điển hình của giống
        \item Tạo ra số lượng giống cần thết để cung cấp cho sản xuất đại trà
        \item Đưa giống tốt phổ biến vào sản xuất
    \end{itemize}

\section{Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng}

    Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng gồm 3 giai đoạn \bigskip

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
    \centering      
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        \node (snc)  {Hạt giống SNC};
        \node (nc) [below of=snc] {Hạt giống NC};
        \node (xn) [below of=nc] {Hạt giống XN};        
        \draw [arrow] (snc) -- (nc);
        \draw [arrow] (nc) -- (xn);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
    \centering      
        \begin{tabular}{ | M{4em} | M{3.5cm}| M{3.5cm} |  } % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \hline
            & \textbf{Chất lượng, độ thuần, nguồn gốc} &\textbf{Nơi thực hiện}  \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Hạt siêu nguyên chủng} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt SNC & Công ty, trung tâm sản xuất giống cây trồng \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Hạt xác nhận} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt NC & Cơ sở nhân giống, trung tâm và các cơ sở sản xuất để sản xuất đại trà \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\section{Quy trình sản xuất giống cây trồng}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | M{4em} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | }
        \hline
        & \textbf{Cây tự thụ phấn} &\textbf{Cây thụ phấn chéo} 
        & \textbf{Cây nhân giống vô tính} & \textbf{Cây rừng}  \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Đặc điểm} & & & & \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Vật liệu khởi đầu} & & & & \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Cách li} & & & & \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Thời gian} & & & & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

**Or** this alternative for the title of the flowchart

[image: zz]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{SNC} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{NC} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{XN} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\setlist[itemize]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{0em}{\centering} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{20pt}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*\School[1]{\gdef\@School{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\Department[1]{\gdef\@Department{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\Author[1]{\gdef\@Author{#1}}
\newcommand\Maketitle{%
    \author{\@Author\\\@School, \@Department}%
    \maketitle
}

\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Bài}   
\makeatother    

\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}        

\begin{document}
    
    \title{{\Huge Công Nghệ 10}}
    \Author{{\large Võ Khắc Phú Cường}}
    \School{{\large THPT Nam Sài Gòn}}
    \Department{{\large 10A1}}
    \date{{\large 2021 – 2022}}
    \Maketitle
\chapter{ Sản xuất giống cây trồng}
    
\section{Mục đích của công tác sản xuất giống cây trồng}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Duy trì, củng cố độ thuần chủng, sức sống và tính trạng điển hình của giống
        \item Tạo ra số lượng giống cần thết để cung cấp cho sản xuất đại trà
        \item Đưa giống tốt phổ biến vào sản xuất
    \end{itemize}

\section{Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng}

\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
    \centering  
Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng gồm 3 giai đoạn \bigskip

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
        \node (snc)  {Hạt giống SNC};
        \node (nc) [below of=snc] {Hạt giống NC};
        \node (xn) [below of=nc] {Hạt giống XN};        
        \draw [arrow] (snc) -- (nc);
        \draw [arrow] (nc) -- (xn);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
    \centering      
        \begin{tabular}{ | M{4em} | M{3.5cm}| M{3.5cm} |  } 
            \hline
            & \textbf{Chất lượng, độ thuần, nguồn gốc} &\textbf{Nơi thực hiện}  \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Hạt siêu nguyên chủng} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt SNC & Công ty, trung tâm sản xuất giống cây trồng \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Hạt xác nhận} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt NC & Cơ sở nhân giống, trung tâm và các cơ sở sản xuất để sản xuất đại trà \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\section{Quy trình sản xuất giống cây trồng}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | M{4em} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | }
        \hline
        & \textbf{Cây tự thụ phấn} &\textbf{Cây thụ phấn chéo} 
        & \textbf{Cây nhân giống vô tính} & \textbf{Cây rừng}  \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Đặc điểm} & & & & \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Vật liệu khởi đầu} & & & & \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Cách li} & & & & \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Thời gian} & & & & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use of `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. Use `\tikzset` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Focused mostly to your problem (without formation of section titles).

With use of `tabularray` package, common settings for the lists, use correct syntax for drawing flowchart and use of two `minipage`s for flowchart and table in parallel (as is suggested in @Simon Dispa, +1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[1]{leftmargin=2.4em}   % <---
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\chapter{}
\section{Mục đích của công tác sản xuất giống cây trồng}
    \begin{itemize}
\item Duy trì, củng cố độ thuần chủng, sức sống và tính trạng điển hình của giống
\item Tạo ra số lượng giống cần thết để cung cấp cho sản xuất đại trà
\item Đưa giống tốt phổ biến vào sản xuất
    \end{itemize}
    
\section{Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng}
    \begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
\centering
Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng gồm 3 giai đoạn 

\vspace{\baselineskip}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
           node distance = 8mm,
             start chain = going below,
every node/.append style = {on chain, join=by -Stealth}
                        ]
\node   {Hạt giống SNC};
\node   {Hạt giống NC};
\node   {Hạt giống XN};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {X[1,c,m, font=\bfseries] X[2,c,m] X[2,c,m]},
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
    &   Chất lượng, độ thuần, nguồn gốc
        &   Nơi thực hiện   \\
Hạt siêu nguyên chủng
    &   Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt SNC 
        &   Công ty, trung tâm sản xuất giống cây trồng \\
Hạt xác nhận
    &   Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt NC 
        & Cơ sở nhân giống, trung tâm và các cơ sở sản xuất để sản xuất đại trà \\
\end{tblr}
\end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    
\section{Quy trình sản xuất giống cây trồng}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {X[1,c,m, font=\bfseries] *{4}{ X[2,c,m]}},
              colsep = 3pt,
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
            &   Cây tự thụ phấn     &   Cây thụ phấn chéo
                &   Cây nhân giống vô tính  &   Cây rừng    \\
Đặc điểm            &   &   &   &   \\
Vật liệu khởi đầu   &   &   &   &   \\
Cách li             &   &   &   &   \\
Thời gian           &   &   &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Note: you may have problems with the appearance of the page since second table is not in float environment.

[image]